# Selenium wait function is not waiting

Tags: java, selenide

I am having Selenium fill out a form for me, but it doesn't seem to be waiting for a form element to load even though I have an explicitly defined wait function for the form item. What might be happening?

Here is the wait function in **IndexInformationQuestions.java**:

```
private static RadioGroup flubber = RadioGroup.withId("Flubber");

public static RadioGroup waitUntilFlubberActive(){
    flubber.getOptionLabel("Flubber 0").shouldBe(enabled).scrollTo().shouldBe(visible);
    return flubber;
  }


  protected SelenideElement getOptionLabel(String text) {
    String xpath =
            ".//label[contains(text(),\""
                    + text
                    + "\")]";
    return this.formGroupDiv.getDiv().$x(xpath);
  }
  public RadioGroup waitUntilActive() {
    flubber.getOptionLabel("Flubber 0").shouldBe(enabled).scrollTo().shouldBe(visible);
    return flubber;
  }
```

And here's an excerpt from the main set of tests in **MichiganPsCreateIndexTest.java** when filling out the form. The point is to call the function to wait for the form item called **flubber** and select the radio button for **Flubber 0**.

```
IndexInformationQuestions.waitUntilFlubberActive();
IndexInformationQuestions.selectFlubber("Flubber 0");
```

When I run the test, our site throws an error that this required element on the form has not been filled out. Is something wrong with the wait function?

Note : We have been advised NOT to use any explicit functions like wait.until or time.sleep().

Comment: While `Thread.sleep()` is certainly not advisable, this is not the same as Selenium implicit or explicit waits. Who advised you NOT to use explicit wait functions and why? This is certainly bad advise. Of the two I mentioned, explicit waits are preferred IMO. The reason for using these Selenium waits is to allow pages to fully load before attempting to interact with elements on a page.

Comment: Regardless, why wouldn't the waitUntilFlubberActive() function serve the same purpose as an explicit wait? If I say something should be visible, shouldn't that make it wait?

Comment: Actually, not "regardless." I just realized you tagged this as "selenium-webdriver" and "selenide". These are two different libraries and you are using "selenide." Now the advise makes more sense. You should be using the wait mechanisms Selenide provides, not Selenium. Since I do not know Selenide like I know Selenium, I cannot advise you further. I would need to get up to speed in order to help you.